# <class 'ValueError'>, ValueError("could not convert string to float: 'X'"),

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to create flask application and I got the following error

```
(<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError("could not convert string to float: 'X'"), <traceback object at 0x0000022B617C0280>)
```

here is my app.py also I have X.csv and Y.csv files in the directory with app.py

```
    imports..

app = Flask(__name__)

X = 'X.csv'
Y = 'Y.csv'

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# Scaling data
sc = StandardScaler()
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)

# Oversample data
smk = SMOTETomek()
# Training data
x_train, y_train = smk.fit_sample(x_train, y_train)
# Testing data
x_test, y_test = smk.fit_sample(x_test, y_test)

# Fitting RandomForestClassifier to the Training set
rfr = RandomForestClassifier()
rfr.fit(x_train, x_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = rfr.predict(x_test)

# Saving model to disk
pickle.dump(rfr, open('model.pkl', 'wb'))

# Loading model to compare the results
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Comment: A complete trace of the error could be helpful. Making a guess, it could be the case that in your CSV files, there is some value that cannot be converted to float. Or at least some value that you are manipulating with the fit model. Just a guess

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please don't "shorten" your imports like that. Imports are actually important.

Assuming that by `train_test_split` you mean `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` documented [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), then the problem is that:

- `X` and `Y` are strings — that is, their values are 'X.csv' and 'Y.csv' respectively.

According to the documentation, the allowed outputs are:

> Allowed inputs are lists, numpy arrays, scipy-sparse matrices or pandas dataframes.

You must open those CSV files using `pandas`, for example.